# Pass NSInteger Score Between View Controllers

Tags: ios

I am creating a game that keeps score as it is played and when the timer expires it moves to a different view controller where I want to display the score, but I cannot make the code work to transfer this value to the next view controller.  This is the code for setting the score.

```
-(void)updateScore
{

NSString *scoreUpdate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Score: %d", myScore];
_theScore.text = scoreUpdate;
NSLog(@"Score Done");
   }
```

I appreciate any help. I know this has been asked before but I cannot get any of the code I have seen to work.  I am also not sure if my method of score keeping allows for this.

Comment: Pick one of the ways attempted/seen and post the code that actually tries to transfer the data to the other vc.  Include _specific_ errors or results that happened or didn't happen.  The current code that sets the score doesn't appear relevant to passing data and the question is too vague (as-is).

Comment: Hi, could you describe how the code in the other question "does not work"? Thanks!